# vkCreateInstance throws Segmentation Fault

Tags: c++, vulkan

I am trying to learn some Vulkan and I have a weird issue with `vkCreateInstance`. It seems to throw segmentation faults but only in very specific circumstances. To be more clear, here is some code:

```
int main() {
    // Load Vulkan Functions, extensions and stuff
    VkApplicationInfo applicationInfo;
    applicationInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_APPLICATION_INFO;
    applicationInfo.pNext = nullptr;
    applicationInfo.pApplicationName = "VulkanDoodles";
    applicationInfo.applicationVersion = VK_MAKE_VERSION(1,0,0);
    applicationInfo.pEngineName = "EngineNamePlaceholder";
    applicationInfo.engineVersion = VK_MAKE_VERSION(1,0,0);
    applicationInfo.apiVersion = VK_MAKE_VERSION(1,0,0);

    VkInstanceCreateInfo instanceCreateInfo;
    instanceCreateInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_INSTANCE_CREATE_INFO;
    instanceCreateInfo.pNext = nullptr;
    instanceCreateInfo.flags = 0;
    instanceCreateInfo.pApplicationInfo = &applicationInfo;
    instanceCreateInfo.ppEnabledLayerNames = nullptr;
    instanceCreateInfo.enabledExtensionCount = (uint32_t)desired_extensions.size();
    instanceCreateInfo.ppEnabledExtensionNames = &desired_extensions[0];

    VkInstance instance;
    if(vk::vkCreateInstance(&instanceCreateInfo, nullptr, &instance) != VK_SUCCESS){
        std::cout << "Could not create instance" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
    // rest of the code
    return 0;
}
```

And it works fine, the instance is created. So i decided to put the code inside a function for readability. But code like the following does not work anymore:

```
VkInstance CreateInstance(const std::vector<const char*> extensions){
    VkApplicationInfo applicationInfo;
    applicationInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_APPLICATION_INFO;
    applicationInfo.pNext = nullptr;
    applicationInfo.pApplicationName = "VulkanDoodles";
    applicationInfo.applicationVersion = VK_MAKE_VERSION(1,0,0);
    applicationInfo.pEngineName = "EngineNamePlaceholder";
    applicationInfo.engineVersion = VK_MAKE_VERSION(1,0,0);
    applicationInfo.apiVersion = VK_MAKE_VERSION(1,0,0);

    VkInstanceCreateInfo instanceCreateInfo;
    instanceCreateInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_INSTANCE_CREATE_INFO;
    instanceCreateInfo.pNext = nullptr;
    instanceCreateInfo.flags = 0;
    instanceCreateInfo.pApplicationInfo = &applicationInfo;
    instanceCreateInfo.ppEnabledLayerNames = nullptr;
    instanceCreateInfo.enabledExtensionCount = (uint32_t)extensions.size();
    instanceCreateInfo.ppEnabledExtensionNames = &extensions[0];
    VkInstance instance;
    if(vk::vkCreateInstance(&instanceCreateInfo, nullptr, &instance) != VK_SUCCESS){
        std::cout << "Could not create instance" << std::endl;
    }
    return instance;
}

int main(){
    // Load Vulkan Functions, extensions and stuff
    VkInstance instance = CreateInstance(desired_extensions);
    // rest of the code
}
```

The call to `vkCreateInstance` throws a segmentation fault. The extensions vector does not seem to be the issue, considering that the next code fragment does work properly:

```
VkInstanceCreateInfo CreateInstanceInfo(const std::vector<const char*>& extensions){
    VkApplicationInfo applicationInfo;
    applicationInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_APPLICATION_INFO;
    applicationInfo.pNext = nullptr;
    applicationInfo.pApplicationName = "VulkanDoodles";
    applicationInfo.applicationVersion = VK_MAKE_VERSION(1,0,0);
    applicationInfo.pEngineName = "EngineNamePlaceholder";
    applicationInfo.engineVersion = VK_MAKE_VERSION(1,0,0);
    applicationInfo.apiVersion = VK_MAKE_VERSION(1,0,0);

    VkInstanceCreateInfo instanceCreateInfo;
    instanceCreateInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_INSTANCE_CREATE_INFO;
    instanceCreateInfo.pNext = nullptr;
    instanceCreateInfo.flags = 0;
    instanceCreateInfo.pApplicationInfo = &applicationInfo;
    instanceCreateInfo.ppEnabledLayerNames = nullptr;
    instanceCreateInfo.enabledExtensionCount = (uint32_t)extensions.size();
    instanceCreateInfo.ppEnabledExtensionNames = &extensions[0];

    return instanceCreateInfo;
}

VkInstance CreateInstance(const VkInstanceCreateInfo& instanceCreateInfo){
    VkInstance instance;
    if(vk::vkCreateInstance(&instanceCreateInfo, nullptr, &instance) != VK_SUCCESS){
        std::cout << "Could not create instance" << std::endl;
    }
    return instance;
}

int main(){
    // Load Vulkan Functions, extensions and stuff
    VkInstanceCreateInfo instanceCreateInfo = CreateInstanceInfo(desired_extensions);
    VkInstance instance = CreateInstance(instanceCreateInfo);
    // rest of the code
}
```

As said before this works fine and my guess would be that the `VkInstanceCreateInfo` variable must be declared inside the `main` function.

So my questions are:

Why does the `vkCreateInstance` throw the segfault? Why only sometimes? Is there something weird happening in there?

Any insight would be very helpfull.

Also for the record, I'm using Linux Mint and CLion with cmake version 3.13 (not sure if that even matters)

Comment: You are returning a local stack variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your middle code snippet is missing `enabledLayerCount` initialization, therefore you make the driver do OOBA.

Your last snippet returns `instanceCreateInfo` where `pApplicationInfo` points to destroyed `VkApplicationInfo` when it is used by `vkCreateInstance`. You make the driver dereference pointer to destroyed memory.

Comment: In C++, what would be the right way of writing a "factory function" that returns a VkInstanceCreateInfo properly? I mean, how to fix `CreateInstanceInfo`?

If we create appInfo locally on stack via then it'll be destroyed after function return. 

We can create one on heap `VkApplicationInfo* ai = new VkApplicationInfo(); /* fill it out */ instanceCreateInfo.pApplicationInfo = ai;`. But that'll keep dangling and put the burden of deletion to function caller.

Is there a way where appInfo on heap gets deleted when `VkInstanceCreateInfo ici = CreateInstanceInfo(exts);` goes out of scope?

Comment: @UğurGüney https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-ValidationLayers/blob/cba0c5000e2f455a44af377fdf2830c2dcd11feb/layers/generated/vk_safe_struct.h#L138

Comment: I see! Thanks for responding on an old thread. This is great! AFAIU, the solution is to provide copyable `safe` versions of these structs whose copy constructors, assignment operators etc are carefully designed to copy data stored in pointers.

Also, very interesting that this code is "generated". Makes sense ,otherwise writing the "safe" Cpp version of the whole Vulkan API would be a very tedious and boring job. :-)